# I can't create an Azure backend template VS 2019

Tags: asp.net, azure, xamarin.forms

I'm following this tutorial https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter1/firstapp_pc/ and at some point it creates an ASP.NET project and loads and Azure Mobile App template.

When I redo these steps in my VS2019 I don't have the option of Azure Mobile App (I have Azure installed). The options are, Empty, Web Forms, MVC, Web API and Single Page Application

There is a backend example that can be downloaded here https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/pull/126. However, if I do that my project and solution already have a name I don't want and it's tedious to change and easy to make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

create function .csproj file manual using below content

```
      <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
   </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
   <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

save this file as myfunction.csproj.
right click solution and choose add existing project and choose project created in step 2
now u can start working on this by adding references and function code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the workaround solutoin provided but I would like to be able to solve the problem directly by creating my own solution based on the template.